# Rooting lenovo s920 after upgrading to kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: rooting, lenovo

how can i root my lenovo s920 upgraded to android 4.4.2 . i have tried the Framaroot method , but it is not working.

Comment: While not being able to answer your question, I've added it to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) – which you might wish to check for alternative methods.

Answer (score -1):

Lenovo S920 and other Mediatek CPU based phones are an easy task, most of the time, to get rooted. There are several tools on the market that can do this with one click. Some of the are iRoot (previous name Vroot), KingoRoot etc. Beware because some of these tools have been uncovered that install malware as well. I have used iRoot in the past without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try using towelroot to root the device. I've never had trouble with any of geohot's apps. Looking further into this it seems your device on 4.4.2 has a lot of issues getting rooted. I take no responsibility for what you do to your device (be very wary of installing malware onto your phone trying out all these sketchy root programs which may or may not work). Anyways, this was the only actual link I found describing someone who successfully rooted it (but it may be malware, the kingoroot is in my opinion - unsafe) http://kumaranmurugan.blogspot.com/2014/11/root-lenovo-s920-kitkat-442-8gb-row.html
Otherwise I've heard FramaRoot 1.6.1 works to root your device. Good luck.